# Terminator Split Screen with uneven split

Tags: terminator

I am hoping to save a terminator config that has an uneven split.  I can manually adjust the split sizes, and save that, but when I relaunch terminator it goes back to being split 50-50.  Here's what I'm trying to have come up by default.

Terminator Version 1.91

Is such a thing supported?

[image: Hopeful Terminator Display Picture]

Here is the generated config file:

```
[global_config]
  suppress_multiple_term_dialog = True
[keybindings]
  close_window = <Primary><Shift>q
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_term = 56328407-5fe2-48df-87dd-6295c2031e48
      last_active_window = True
      maximised = True
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      position = 67:27
      size = 1853, 1145
      title = joe@ubuntuvm: ~
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 922
      ratio = 0.498917748918
      type = HPaned
    [[[child3]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      position = 569
      ratio = 0.499122807018
      type = VPaned
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 56328407-5fe2-48df-87dd-6295c2031e48
    [[[terminal4]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child3
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = fa4d9c58-de5a-43d1-bb97-6277fb6368b5
    [[[terminal5]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child3
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 10b03cb2-2a83-48a2-8433-4d7d7ac274ec
  [[test]]
    [[[child0]]]
      fullscreen = False
      last_active_term = 56328407-5fe2-48df-87dd-6295c2031e48
      last_active_window = False
      maximised = True
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      position = 67:27
      size = 1853, 1145
      title = joe@ubuntuvm: ~
      type = Window
    [[[child1]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child0
      position = 946
      ratio = 0.829824561404
      type = VPaned
    [[[terminal2]]]
      order = 0
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = fa4d9c58-de5a-43d1-bb97-6277fb6368b5
    [[[terminal3]]]
      order = 1
      parent = child1
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      uuid = 10b03cb2-2a83-48a2-8433-4d7d7ac274ec
[plugins]
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    cursor_color = "#aaaaaa"
    palette = "#000000:#cc0000:#4e9a06:#c4a
```

Answer (score 0):

On layouts settings click on the "Type" -> "Window" -> "Terminal" and chose the profile you want to link with this layout.

You can also use:

```
terminator --layout customname
```

to run terminator with specific layout.

or

```
terminator -s
```

to get the selection box so you can select specific layout.

With these command you may also add an keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu keyboard settings.

Comment: I am already doing this.  That gives me a screen with the top and the bottom identical in width, but I want a screen where the top and the bottom have different widths.  Looking into the config file it generates, it appears to give size recommendations, but they aren't being used.